# how can load html page in a dialogue and open as popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this separate html page which i want to open as dialogue in click of a button, is this possible? how can we do this?

```
<div id="dialog-form" title="Change Password"> 
      <form>
        <div class="border">
          <label for="oldPassword">Old Password</label>
          <input type="password" id ="oldPassword" placeholder="Enter Old Password">
          <label for="newPassword">New Password</label>
          <input type="password" id="newPassword" placeholder="Enter New Password">
          <label for="retypePassword">Retype Password</label>
          <input type="password" id="retypePassword" placeholder="Enter Retype password">
        </div>
          <div class="buttons">
            <button id="submit">Submit</button>
            <button id="cancel">Cancel</button>
         </div>
      </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: i tried on button click  $('<div>').load(page name); but this is not working

Comment: i am new in jquery,javascript

Answer (score 3):

Yes and have a look at the link below to accomplish this, its pretty straight forward:

[link](http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/jquerymobile_popups.asp)

Since you did not want to use jquery mobile pop up

do this :

```
$('#dialog-form').click(function(){
  window.open('url', 'window name', 'window settings');
  return false;
});
```

at url, paste the link of the html file and also, you can name your window and add additional settings like height , width etc, if you are fine with the answer you can vote it positively thank you :)

Comment: thanks for this:) but i don't want jquery mobile pop up .actually i want to open this given html page as dailog in relative to window.

Answer (score 3):

For such think I suggest to use a style Framework like JQuery UI.

It's pretty simple and easily Setup:

For your example you would use:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog();
    });
  </script>
</head>

<div id="dialog-form" title="Change Password"> 
  <form>
    <div class="border">
      <label for="oldPassword">Old Password</label>
      <input type="password" id ="oldPassword" placeholder="Enter Old Password">
      <label for="newPassword">New Password</label>
      <input type="password" id="newPassword" placeholder="Enter New Password">
      <label for="retypePassword">Retype Password</label>
      <input type="password" id="retypePassword" placeholder="Enter Retype password">
    </div>
      <div class="buttons">
        <button id="submit">Submit</button>
        <button id="cancel">Cancel</button>
     </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Have a look at this: https://jqueryui.com/dialog/

EDIT:

As Robert pointed out that you might Need to open the dialog from another Content page, you can use `jQuery.load()` Method with a callback to open the dialog:

```
$('#dialog-form').load('path-to-my-page', function() { $('#dialog-form).dialog('open'); });
```

Comment: if the page is separate, maybe add an ajax call examle to your post, so the page can be loaded from other action/page.

Answer (score 3):

You want to create a dialog, and add different HTML code by clicking different button?

1.Create a div, make it looks like a dialog. Don`t display it.

```
<div id="dialog-form" title="Change Password" style="display: none;"> </div>
```

2.Define variable like this:

```
var html = '<form>' +
    '<div class="border">' +
      '<label for="oldPassword">Old Password</label>' +
      '<input type="password" id ="oldPassword" placeholder="Enter Old Password">' +
      '<label for="newPassword">New Password</label>' +
      '<input type="password" id="newPassword" placeholder="Enter New Password">' +
      '<label for="retypePassword">Retype Password</label>' +
      '<input type="password" id="retypePassword" placeholder="Enter Retype password">' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="buttons">' +
      '<button id="submit">Submit</button>' +
      '<button id="cancel">Cancel</button>' +
    '</div>' +
'</form>';
```

3.Add `$('#dialog-form').html(html).css('display', 'block');` in click handler.

Your can also hide the dialog by `$('#dialog-form').html('').css('display', 'none');`.

Comment: Thanks for reply:) .this is looking great but this is showing form in same page instead of opening a dailog

Answer (score 3):

You easily open a dialog on button click using bootstrap.

If you use template for your project and you want to open a dialog on button click then sometimes jquery dialog not provide proper output as my experience so i use `bootstrap` dialog(model).

```
<div class="container">
   <h2>Small Modal</h2>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dialog-form">Change Password</button>

   <div id="dialog-form" title="Change Password" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
     <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
      <div class="modal-content">
      <form>
      <div class="border">
        <label for="oldPassword">Old Password</label>
        <input type="password" id ="oldPassword" placeholder="Enter Old Password">
        <label for="newPassword">New Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="newPassword" placeholder="Enter New Password">
        <label for="retypePassword">Retype Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="retypePassword" placeholder="Enter Retype password">
      </div>
      <div class="buttons">
        <button id="submit">Submit</button>
        <button id="cancel">Cancel</button>
      </div>
      </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```